# How to detect connection status

Tags: iphone, ios, network-programming

I am using AsyncSocket in my iPhone telnet based app to communicate with sever. Communication is working fine.

If some one plug out the LAN cable from server. I want my app should show some alert.

Does anyone has any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Add an observer for the Network Reachability like this

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                     selector:@selector(myReachabilityDidChangedMethod)
                                         name:kReachabilityChangedNotification
                                       object:nil];
Reachability *reachability;
reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
[reachability startNotifier];
```

So when ever Network state changes you will be notified using Observer Method -

```
(void)myReachabilityDidChangedMethod:(Reachability*){

}
```

Comment: I want check the reachabilty for socket. not for Internet.
And how cani associate this with my socket.